# How to hide or show correctly page element (with media query of pure css)?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have two class:

```
.show{display:block; visibility: visible;}
.hide{display:hidden; visibility: hidden;}
```

My dilemma is when screen width greater than 768px, Media query makes `.hide` on some element effectively, The element will be gone. That's my expectance. But when screen width smaller than 768px, Mediq query makes `.show` on some **inline-block** element effectively and there is a issue. Because the `disable:block` of `.show` class modify the element's model box.

Simply illustrate:

```
<span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span>
```

Add the `.show` will be turned:

```
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
```

How do I avoid change the model box when I want a element be visible?

---

**UPDATE**:
I have a answer not yet test.

```
.show{visibility: visible;height: auto;}
.hide{visibility: hidden; height: 0;}
```

Comment: use jquery function hide() and show(). It will deal with block and inline-block elements.

Comment: @Borachio I want to media query achieve it, and no js lib.because I use media screen to do a response page

Comment: How are you adding classes with only pure CSS?

Comment: @winterblood use media screen (){`show` or `hide`}. 'add' maybe a lit inaccurate. In other word, use media screen to control different class to achieve effect like as add a class.

Comment: Does my updated answer not work? With the added advantage that you only need one class. Also note from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility) *"The `hidden` value hides an element but leaves space where it would have been."* Which is why `display:none` is normaly used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not only `display` can be achieved it. 
you can use `visibility` `height`. Like this:

```
.show{visibility: visible;height: auto;}
.hide{visibility: hidden; height: 0;}
```

Comment: Just make sure you understand the difference between `visibility:hidden` and `display:none`.  By default `visibility:hidden` maintains space for the element in the display, `display:none` does not, this is why you need to change height too. To cover everything you should also add `width:0` to hide.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with for inline elements

```
.show {display:inline;}
.hide {display:none;}
```

Or for CSS3 only `.show {display:initial;}`

Another option would be to code around you're elements, but it gets messy

```
.hide {display:none;}
.show {display:inline;}
a.show, span.show, ...etc {display:inline;}
td.show {display:table-cell;}
```

You can see where this is headed.

You're better off just removing the `.hide` class than adding the `.show` class as well. By just removing the `hide` class or adjusting your media query, the element should rever to its natural state.

**Update** as you mention media queries, perhaps this is more of an example of what you are after:

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 50em) {
    .hideNarrow {display:none;}    
}
```

```html
<span class="hideNarrow">Will go</span>
<span>Will Stay</span>
<span class="hideNarrow">Will go</span>
<span>Will Stay</span>
<span class="hideNarrow">Will go</span>
<span>Will Stay</span>
<span class="hideNarrow">Will go</span>
<span>Will Stay</span>
<span class="hideNarrow">Will go</span>
<span>Will Stay</span>
<span class="hideNarrow">Will go</span>
```

PLay with it here where you can slide the page width: http://jsfiddle.net/of2yc9nu/2/

Comment: sorry, But this is not fit for **block** element.

Comment: Wasn't your question regarding inline elements?

Comment: Thanks a lot. The way that you resolve the question give me a new path to my purpose.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
.show {
   display: inherit;
}
```

Comment: This won't work if an inline elements parent is `block` or anything other than `inline`.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
.show {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<span class="show">1</span>
<span class="hide">2</span>
<span class="show">3</span>
<span class="hide">4</span>
<span class="show">5</span>
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
.show{
    visibility : visible;
    height: auto;
}
.hide{
    visibility : hidden;
    height: 0;
}
```

```html
<span class="show">Span1</span>
<span class="show">Span2</span>
<span class="hide">Span3</span>

<div class="show">div1</div>
<div class="show">div2</div>
```

This will work.

Comment: How is jQuery pure CSS?